# Can't move the viewport after updating from 2.69 to 2.78

Tags: 3d-view

I just updated Blender to 2.78, and now I can't move the viewport with Option-Click and drag. I can select objects but I can't move the viewport.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that not all of the settings were copied over from your old blender version into 2.78 when you installed it.

As far as I know, the option to move the mouse with <kbd>Option (or Alt)</kbd>+<kbd>Click and Drag</kbd> isn't enabled by default, but can be enabled by checking the 'Emulate 3 Button Mouse' box under the `Input` panel of the User Preferences.

[image: Screenshot of User Prefs]